# I was using pysimplegui and i want to position button on the right side

Tags: python, pysimplegui

if i put element_justification as center i get button on the center, if i put element_justification on the right then text is also on the right even thoguht i putted justification in the text separately, i need text in center and button align to the right of the window.

```
    import PySimpleGUI as sg
    layout = [[sg.Text('Nešto ne štima', text_color="", font=(
        'Helvetica', 30), justification='center', key='rezultat1')],
        [sg.Text('Nije se spojilo na net', text_color="", font=(
            'Helvetica', 20), justification='center', visible=False, key='rezultat')],
        [sg.Button('?', size=(0, 0), visible=True, font=(
        'Helvetica', 20), key='go')], [sg.Button('Enter','center', visible=False, 
    key='gumb')]]
    win = sg.Window('Proba', layout, element_justification='center')
    while True:
        e, v = win.read()
        if e == 'go':
            win.Element('rezultat').Update('Nije se spojilo na net', visible=True)
        if e == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            win.close()
            break
```

Comment: i just found an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68929799/pysimplegui-right-justify-a-button-in-a-frame

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're something about the alignment of elements.

1. Option `justification` in `sg.Text` means the alignment of multiline text in available space. So it will be nothing different if only one line and same space for it.
2. `element_justification` in `sg.Window` means all elements in the Window itself will have this justification if not specified.
3. To align an element, you need more space for element to aligned, otherwise there will be nothing different. So add a `sg.Column` as container for elements to align inside of it, and set `expand_x` to `True` to expand the space of `sg.Column`, after it, you can set `element_justification` of `sg.Column` to align the elements in it.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

col_layout = [
    [sg.Button('?', size=(0, 0), visible=True, font=('Helvetica', 20), key='go')],
    [sg.Button('Enter', visible=False, key='gumb')],    # second position argument for button type, cannot use 'center'
]

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Nešto ne štima', text_color="", font=('Helvetica', 30), key='rezultat1')],
    [sg.Text('Nije se spojilo na net', text_color="", font=('Helvetica', 20), visible=False, key='rezultat')],
    [sg.Column(col_layout, element_justification='right', expand_x=True)],
]
win = sg.Window('Proba', layout, element_justification='center')

while True:
    e, v = win.read()
    if e == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif e == 'go':
        win['rezultat'].update(visible=True)

win.close()
```

4. Use `sg.Push()`/`sg.VPush()` to push other elements at same/different row in horizontal/vertical direction.

Comment: thanks alot, u also helped me on my last question